# Laravel, какое отношение выбрать

Tags: laravel

Есть таблица

role в ней хранятся список ролей пользователя

id | name |

1 - Директор
2 - Старший менеджер
3 - Главный представитель
4 - Тернер

role_access в ней планируется хранятся список ролей и какие они могут добавлять роли при будущем создании пользователей, к примеру

role_id | access_id

1 - 1,2,3,4

3 - 4

То есть Директор может добавить пользователя со всеми ролями, а Главный представитель только Тренера, надеюсь правильно объяснил

Как мне это реализовать ?

Answer (score 1):

Сделать модели Role и UserRole с таблицами. Связь Many To Many. Логику добавления в таблицу user_role реализовывать в коде, не в таблицах. Права доступа проверять с помощью Laravel Policy. 
Сделать политику в UserPolicy

```
public function attachRole(User $user)
{
   return $user->isAdmin();
}
```

Добавить в модель User проверку на админа (или проверку на роль пользователя, которые могут добавлять роли)

```
const ID__ADMIN = 4;

public function isAdmin()
{
  return $this->id === self::ID__ADMIN;
}
```

И проверять в контроллере перед добавлением роли

```
$user = Auth::user();

$this->authorize('attachRole', $user);
```